# Is there an API for grep, pipe, cat in groovy?

Tags: unix, groovy

Is there an API for grep, pipe, cat in groovy?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Not sure I understand your question.

Do you mean make system calls and pipe the results?

If so, you can just do something like:

```
println 'cat /Users/tim_yates/.bash_profile'.execute().text
```

To print the contents of a file

You can pipe process output as well:

```
def proc = 'cat /Users/tim_yates/.bash_profile'.execute() | 'grep git'.execute()
println proc.text
```

If you want to get the text of a `File` using standard Groovy API calls, you can do:

```
println new File( '/Users/tim_yates/.bash_profile' ).text
```

And this gets a list of the lines in a file, finds all that contain the word `git` then prints each one out in turn:

```
new File( '/Users/tim_yates/.bash_profile' ).text.tokenize( '\n' ).findAll {
  it.contains 'git'
}.each {
  println it
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted :)

Comment: Obviously, if the files are massive, you'll want to scan them on a line-by-line basis with `File.eachLine` rather than the `File.text.tokenize` code above, which loads the whole file into RAM.  Good luck and have fun!

Comment: Blogged about what I used it for : http://schulstad.blogspot.com/2011/03/logs-use-groovygrep-to-find-trends-in.html

Comment: I would suggest that you replace .tokenize( '\n' ) with .readLines().  That would be cleaner and more system-independent.

Comment: Good idea. That method wasn't in groovy until 6 months after this answer